# HP BIOS Issue AFTER installing Ubuntu

Tags: hp, bios

I have an old HP 6560b Notebook, that I wanted to totally clean up... I decided to install Ubunutu, and everything went Ok with the install until I needed to restart to notebook.

I now get a Media test failure message (fyi: when I run the hard disk test from the diagnostic screen it passes)

I now ONLY get the System Diagnostics, no BIOS options at all. I've been looking around and have tried to update the BIOS, (using sp85528.exe from HP website, and other) but:

1. I cannot create a BIOS boot stick (I just don't see this option when I run the update on another computer)
2. After manually creating a boot stick, the boot process does not see it

Is there ANYTHING I can do now...?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what does and other in this statement from your question mean? using sp85528.exe from HP website, and other

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu installation would mess with BIOS. How did you install Ubuntu? through USB stick? Try to connect the same and boot. See what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies,
David the "and other" should have read "others" as I tried some older updates files

As it happens I tried installing "Ubuntu Studio", and this has worked out perfectly, so everything is now sorted....

Thanks again...